# How to save only certain bytes I need instead of all in an array?

Tags: c, stm32, uart

I am getting from a sensor via UART communication every second 10 bytes. But I don't need all bytes, actually only certain bytes to work with. Now what I do is to save all bytes into an array and create two new `uint8_t`'s and assign them the byte from the buffer array I need.

Is there a way to only receive and save the bytes I need in the first place instead of all 10?

```
uint8_t buffer[10];

HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart4, (uint8_t*)buffer, 10)

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart4)
{
  uint8_t value1 = buffer[4];
  uint8_t value2 = buffer[5];
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: If you get 10 bytes from the UART, you need to read them, period. Read all 10 bytes, then deal with them.

Comment: If you are setting up a DMA transfer, and handling your data in a callback, which is what your code looks like, then code like you've shown is surely your best bet.

Comment: **IF** you were reading characters from a file descriptor or stream, using (say) functions from `<stdio.h>`, you'd have other options, but they would still involve explicitly reading and discarding the bytes you don't need.

Comment: What's this fishy cast for? `(uint8_t*)buffer`

Comment: Also DMA buffers generally need to be `volatile`. Is the ST function copying data from the actual DMA buffer or is your array supposed to be that buffer? You also need to declare variables shared with callbacks as `volatile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with just raw interrupt handling, without any DMA and (mostly) without fancy HAL functions.

You'll have to write manual UART interrupt handler for RXNE flag, which is set when UART receives signle character. Read it from DR register and decide - save or discard it. Of cource it's up to you now, to count all received bytes and detect "end of message" condition.

OR

If your code have nothing to do during receiving this message, use

> HAL_UART_Receive

To read message byte-by-byte

Answer (score 1):

In DMA mode you need to provide the full size buffer. There is no other way as reception is not controlled by the core (it is done ion the background) and the DMA controller signals end (ad if you want half and error conditions) of the transaction only